# Where is node's certificate store?

Tags: macos, node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am making an https request (using the request module) to a server with a self-signed cert.  It throws an error if I don't specify `strictSSL: false` as an option.

This cert is already trusted on my OS (OSX), such that Chrome doesn't throw an error while accessing a webpage from that server.

I understand different applications/environments may have their own certificate stores.  Firefox has its own, and the JVM, for example, is usually at $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts (on OSX).

My question is, where does node look for its trusted CA's?  Is there such a concept?  I'd like to add my self-signed cert there for development purposes.

Comment: I don't know where they are stored, but you can add CA to this `https.globalAgent.options.ca = your CA`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is not a store.  You can pass a `ca` option to the https request to tell it what CAs you do trust.

From [the docs](https://node.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/https/#httpsrequestoptions-callback):

> The following options from `tls.connect()` can also be specified.
>   However, a `globalAgent` silently ignores these.
>
> - `ca`: An authority certificate or array of authority certificates to check 
>     the remote host against.
>
> In order to specify these options, use a custom `Agent`.
>
> ```
> var options = {
>   ...
>   ca: CA or [array of CAs]
>   ...
> };
>
> options.agent = new https.Agent(options);
>
> var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
> ```

Ref: http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback

Answer (score 12):

It seems that while there is no store, but there is a default list of CA's built into the source.

My search ultimately led me to the closest thing to a store, this file of CA's that node.js supports:

https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/node_root_certs.h

Thus, while it is true that it doesn't do a lookup on the system hosted CA's and that there is no "store" per se, there is a default list of CA's that it accepts.

As mentioned by @Joe and @damphat, you can add your own with the Agent.options.ca property, unfortunately that workaround isn't practical in my case.

Comment: Since 7.3 there’s https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_extra_ca_certs_file which is a bit closer to adding arbitrary ones through the system