# SSL Inspection error:CERT_UNTRUSTED when adding meteor package

Tags: node.js, ssl, meteor, certificate, ssl-certificate

At work we are behind an SSL inspection appliance which resigns all traffic with the companies root CA. Is there a way to add this certificate to Meteor.

When not suing meteor we can tell NPM where our CA cert lives:

```
npm config set cafile /path/to/cert.pem
```

Is there a way to add the certificate to Meteor's trusted list?

Here is the error in full:

```
$ meteor add twbs:bootstrap
Unable to update package catalog (are you offline?)

If you are using Meteor behind a proxy, set HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY
environment variables or see this page for more details:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Meteor-behind-a-proxy

 => Errors while adding packages:             

While downloading twbs:bootstrap@3.3.4...:
error: CERT_UNTRUSTED

Your package catalog may be out of date.      
Please connect to the internet and try again.
```

And just to show that I have the proxy properly configured

```
$ printenv | grep -i proxy
http_proxy=http://gatekeeper-w.<my company>.org:80/
https_proxy=http://gatekeeper-w.<my company>.org:80/
HTTP_PROXY=http://gatekeeper-w.<my company>.org:80/
HTTPS_PROXY=http://gatekeeper-w.<my company>.org:80/
```

EDIT.

I was able to turn on verbose logging in the meteor cli:

```
$ meteor add twbs:bootstrap
Opening db file /home/techplex/.meteor/package-metadata/v2.0.1/packages.data.db
In remote catalog refresh
Unable to update package catalog (are you offline?)

If you are using Meteor behind a proxy, set HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables or see this page for more details:  https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Meteor-behind-a-proxy
Network error: wss://packages.meteor.com/websocket: CERT_UNTRUSTED
Error: Network error: wss://packages.meteor.com/websocket: CERT_UNTRUSTED
    at Object.Future.wait (/home/techplex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:398:15)
    at new ServiceConnection (/home/techplex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/service-connection.js:85:17)
    at Object.exports.openServiceConnection (/home/techplex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/auth-client.js:12:10)
    at openPackageServerConnection (/home/techplex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/package-client.js:22:21)
    at _updateServerPackageData (/home/techplex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/package-client.js:151:14)
    at /home/techplex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/package-client.js:130:12
    at /home/techplex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:327:18
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/techplex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
    at /home/techplex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:326:36
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/techplex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
    at Object.enterJob (/home/techplex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:317:26)
    at Object.exports.updateServerPackageData (/home/techplex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/package-client.js:129:23)
    at /home/techplex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/catalog-remote.js:784:36
    at /home/techplex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:327:18
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/techplex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
    at /home/techplex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:326:36
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/techplex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
    at Object.enterJob (/home/techplex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:317:26)
    at [object Object]._.extend.refresh (/home/techplex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/catalog-remote.js:783:18)
    at Object.catalog.refreshOrWarn (/home/techplex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/catalog.js:48:22)
    at [object Object].catalog.Refresh.OnceAtStart.beforeCommand (/home/techplex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/catalog.js:21:16)
    at /home/techplex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/main.js:1359:32
    at /home/techplex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:327:18
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/techplex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
    at /home/techplex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:326:36
    at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/home/techplex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
    at Object.enterJob (/home/techplex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:317:26)
    at /home/techplex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/main.js:1358:20
    - - - - -
    at packages/ddp/stream_client_nodejs.js:178:1
    at packages/ddp/stream_client_nodejs.js:168:1
    at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:108:1)

Failed to update package catalog, but will continue.
Local package version is up-to-date: autopublish@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: autoupdate@1.2.1
Local package version is up-to-date: base64@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: binary-heap@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: blaze@2.1.2
Local package version is up-to-date: blaze-tools@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: boilerplate-generator@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: callback-hook@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: check@1.0.5
Local package version is up-to-date: ddp@1.1.0
Local package version is up-to-date: deps@1.0.7
Local package version is up-to-date: ejson@1.0.6
Local package version is up-to-date: fastclick@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: geojson-utils@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: html-tools@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: htmljs@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: http@1.1.0
Local package version is up-to-date: id-map@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: insecure@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: jquery@1.11.3_2
Local package version is up-to-date: json@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: launch-screen@1.0.2
Local package version is up-to-date: livedata@1.0.13
Local package version is up-to-date: logging@1.0.7
Local package version is up-to-date: meteor@1.1.6
Local package version is up-to-date: meteor-platform@1.2.2
Local package version is up-to-date: minifiers@1.1.5
Local package version is up-to-date: minimongo@1.0.8
Local package version is up-to-date: mobile-status-bar@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: mongo@1.1.0
Local package version is up-to-date: observe-sequence@1.0.6
Local package version is up-to-date: ordered-dict@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: random@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: reactive-dict@1.1.0
Local package version is up-to-date: reactive-var@1.0.5
Local package version is up-to-date: reload@1.1.3
Local package version is up-to-date: retry@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: routepolicy@1.0.5
Local package version is up-to-date: session@1.1.0
Local package version is up-to-date: spacebars@1.0.6
Local package version is up-to-date: spacebars-compiler@1.0.6
Local package version is up-to-date: templating@1.1.1
Local package version is up-to-date: tracker@1.0.7
Local package version is up-to-date: ui@1.0.6 
Local package version is up-to-date: underscore@1.0.3
Local package version is up-to-date: url@1.0.4
Local package version is up-to-date: webapp@1.2.0
Local package version is up-to-date: webapp-hashing@1.0.3
Downloading missing local versions of package twbs:bootstrap@3.3.4 : [ 'os.linux.x86_64' ]
Doing HTTP request:  GET https://warehouse.meteor.com/builds/es6a7rEJcykSMuMXC/1426521397384/JrJdwdpCXA/twbs:bootstrap-3.3.4-os+web.browser+web.cordova.tgz
 => Errors while adding packages:             

While downloading twbs:bootstrap@3.3.4...:
error: CERT_UNTRUSTED

Your package catalog may be out of date.      
Please connect to the internet and try again.
```

Comment: Not an expert on this but shouldn't HTTPS_PROXY be using a https address? e.g. `https://gatekeeper-w.<my company>.org:443`

Comment: @MichaelMason It probably should be but <my company> doesn't have an HTTPS proxy setup. I've tried it.

Comment: Only other thing, have you tried without the trailing slashes after the port `:80`?

Comment: @MichaelMason I've tried with removing the trailing slash. No change, same error. I don't think its a proxy issue, I think its how the SSL Inspection alliance works by basically Man-In-The-Middle all of our traffic then resigning the traffic with the companies self signed Root CA. I've added the certificate to Linux's OpenSSL store, browsing the web works but I don't think node/meteor is reading the OS's certificate store.

Comment: In that case I'm not sure if there's a way around except by creating a local fork of meteor and editing the relevant code. It seems node doesn't have/use a CA store per-se but does have some built-in CAs which it trusts (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/21006910/2723753). I think you could edit https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/2ccaf6a51e289ffb7bdca9e5645621f27b706672/tools/http-helpers.js#L171 and add a line something like  `options.ca = "contents of your CA pem file"`

Comment: Adding the `options.ca = "contents of your CA pem file"` allows me to download packages, but the cli still can't download the package catalog. Not having the catalog isn't a huge deal, I'm hoping that dependency resolution won't be an issue. I dug deeper into how the catalog is downloaded and it looks like its over a dde/websocket connection using the faye-websocket npm module. Its not abundantly clear to me how that module would accept a new CA to trust. I suppose that is a different question. @MichaelMason If you want to make an answer based on this discussion. I'll mark is as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the suggestions of @Michael Mason I was able to develop a patch for Meteor which allows operation behind an SSL Inspection proxy.

The patch adds add support for the CAFILE environemnt variable which works very similarly to how NPM accepts additional Root Certificates.

Simply add `export CAFILE=/path/to/root/cert.crt` to your .bashrc, and logout and back in.

I hope this helps others.

You can see the full content of the Pull Request here:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/5523

Comment: I just commented on that issue. The solution does not work for me, running Rocket.Chat (built on Meteor). I am using it from a snap but can confirm, having set the env. vars via service config overrides, that CAFILE is set in the running processes. Nonetheless, I still get SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN errors in the logs.