# How to add an accounts-password package?

Tags: node.js, meteor

My platform is windows 7.I want to add the accounts-password package. But I got a "error:CERT_UNTRUSTED".

This is all output error message.

> AppData\Local.meteor\leaderboard>..\meteor add accounts-password
>
> Unable to update package catalog (are you offline?)
>
> If you are using Meteor behind a proxy, set HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY
>   environment variables or see this page for more details:
>   https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Meteor-behind-a-proxy
>
> => Errors while adding packages:
>
> While downloading npm-bcrypt@0.7.8_2...: error: CERT_UNTRUSTED
>
> Your package catalog may be out of date. Please connect to the
>   internet and try again.

Blockquote

I don't know how to fix this problem. Or is there a alternative manual way to add this accounts-password package. Have any suggestions? Many thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSL Inspection error:CERT\_UNTRUSTED when adding meteor package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31457594/ssl-inspection-errorcert-untrusted-when-adding-meteor-package)

Comment: I think a SSL inspection error occurs, all packages will not be add.But I can add the accounts-ui package. Add the accounts-password package I got "error:CERT_UNTRUSTED".

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in "pa ssword".

Run:

```
meteor add accounts-password
```

You'll be good to go.

Comment: try running meteor update and then running the same command again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are behind the firewall which is conducting SSL Inspection (so it is replacing SSL certificate). If it is so - ask your system administrator to turn off SSL Inspection for your machine and try again.