# node certificate store, does node read only from hard coded list of certificates?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, https

After struggling for a while, is there any way to add new
certificate to the list of certificates node trusts?

It seems that node will trust **only** to certificates stored in **hard coded** list of certificates: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/node_root_certs.h

So for example, node app should communicate with `https://foo-bar-baz.com` that use self signed certificate, causing request to that domain to return something like: 
 `[RequestError: Error: certificate has expired]`

Apparently how this can be fixed in java is adding `https://foo-bar-baz.com`certificate to `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts`.

Does node **only** read certificates from mentioned hard coded list? or it can read also from some OS certificate store? **If just from hard coded list:**

1. Why? What can be the reason to implement it in that way?
2. If some certificate gets forged, only what one can do is to wait next node version?
3. If one want to add self-signed certificate, impossible?

(One could edit probably hard coded list to add/remove certificate, but i wouldn't feel comfortable with changing node source, also from similar question [Where is node's certificate store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21004645/where-is-nodes-certificate-store) one could add certificate while doing request but it is not in scope of this question. Similar question is posted before 2 years, and from what i have investigated situation is the same today)

Comment: It appears that Node just uses the system certificate store.

Comment: Various sources on Google

Comment: Which sources? Links? I tested adding certificate following http://superuser.com/questions/437330/how-do-you-add-a-certificate-authority-ca-to-ubuntu and verify that certificate was added successfully but node ignore it

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. Node should recognize any local trusted cert as verified. If it isn't, try rebooting and stuff.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling them hard coded "list of certificates" ... the list is Certificate Granting Authorities, not certificates ... current behaviour is intentional for good reasons ... it would be very bad if a web server (nodejs) rendered a Green Padlock for unvalidated toy self signed certs

I suggest you use a better technique to synthesize your certificates which will give you valid certs which enable that Green Padlock ...

Run through this tutorial to get valid certs (free) for your domain which are production ready ... also gr8 for kicking tyres  : [https://letsecure.me/secure-web-deployment-with-lets-encrypt-and-nginx/](https://letsecure.me/secure-web-deployment-with-lets-encrypt-and-nginx)

Comment: regarding list, but again they are `certificates` that belong to certification authorities (CA) itself, (if root, digitally signed by them self) right? second, of course that it would be bad to render Green Padlock for unvalidated self signed certs in production environment, but again it can be discussed should that be banned at all as you are saying or it should be strongly not recommended. There are many sites that are running on self signed certs anyway. The reason why i can't accept your answer is that i didn't ask how to get valid certs