# CERT_UNTRUSTED error when execute https request

Tags: node.js, https, node-request

I am trying to execute `https request` from my *node server* side but it give me following error :-

```
Caught exception: Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED
```

If i execute `http request` then it's working fine but for `https` **links** **its not working**.

Here is my code:-

```
var request = require('request');
request('https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrid_Olofsdotter_of_Sweden', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage.
  }
})
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Maybe you should check your network environment?
I run your code, and work fine.

Comment: How to  check  network ennvironment. code is working fine on local but not on production. I am facing issue on wikipidea url  like https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrid_Olofsdotter_of_Sweden

Comment: Could you see console log of production environment? Maybe try to print out error log `console.log(error)`

Comment: i am getting this Caught exception: Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED

Comment: i am facing this issue on wikipidea urls like above mention link

Comment: How about add `,{strictSSL: false}` option after url parameter.

Comment: Still having same issue.

Comment: Just for test purposes - did you try downloading the wikipedia.com cert in a PEM format, and then specifying it as a trusted cert as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21004645/where-is-nodes-certificate-store ?

Comment: which version `npm` and `node` are you using?

Comment: @pritishvaidya  my npm version is 2.5.1 and node version is v0.12.0

Comment: you can either try the *latest versions if that is feasible* or check if there is any `proxy or vpn` which causes the problem

Answer (score 3):

This could be down to a number of things, Ive run your code and its fine for me

```
node --version
v0.12.5
```

so I would look at

1. the version of nodejs you are using

periodically root certificates are updated , i would suggest updating as it could possibly be that the cert used is newer than the root certificates in your distribution and is hence showing as untrusted

2. network - its possible that you are behind a proxy that does something unexpected with your requests
3. the target server , it could be returning something unexpected.

The most likely is 1, that you are using a version of nodejs that doesnt recognise the certificate provider of the site and therefore says that its untrusted.

I'd put 2 and 3 about the same level of likelyhood. if you are spidering wikipedia, its possible they've blocked you / pushed you to an error page where the certificate may not be valid.

Whilst you can , as the other posters have suggested, turn off verification, I would advise against it as a habit. And never do it in production environments.

The only time I break this rule is for self signed certificates on local machines.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a SSL issue, Best way to fix SSL of Network Environment.

---

For now you can bypass issue by making rejectUnauthorized as `false`

```
const request = require("request");
const https = require('https');
const agentOptions = {
    host: 'en.m.wikipedia.org',
    port: '443',
    path: '/wiki/Astrid_Olofsdotter_of_Sweden',
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};
const agent = new https.Agent(agentOptions);

const postOption = {
    method: 'GET',
    agent: agent,
    uri: 'https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrid_Olofsdotter_of_Sweden'
};

request(postOption, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass https using below commands:

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

Setting strict-ssl false allows all the node server to access any url.

or set the registry URL from https or http like below:

```
npm config set registry="http://registry.npmjs.org/"
```

**Note:** However, Personally I believe bypassing https is not the real solution, but we can use it as a workaround.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not using SSL isn't really an answer to the question, as you seem to know, based on your note. Presumably, arun wants to have SSL working in their app. Also, in comments to the question, arun says that after adding strictSSL: false to the options the error is still there.

Answer (score 0):

A very close answer is located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888610/ignore-invalid-self-signed-ssl-certificate-in-node-js-with-https-request).

A very detailed & specific answer to this question is given [here](https://thequietinnovator.com/2015/10/11/how-to-fix-nodejs-cert_untrusted-issues/).

I would recommend the following:

Before calling `https.request()` set:

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
```

In the agent options, set:

```
const agentOptions = {    
    ... 
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};
```

Also, refer to the [documentation for TLS/SSL of request library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#tlsssl-protocol).