# LetsEncrypt root certificate expiry breaks Azure Function Node application

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, lets-encrypt

I have a node application running as an Azure function.
Every 60 seconds it makes a number of web api calls, and one of the web apis has its SSL certificate signed by LetsEncrypt (R3).

On September 30th 2021 a root certificate expired. https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/

Now the function fails to call the API. (See the error below).

Where would the fault be?

- Is the fault in NodeJS itself? Does it have its own set of root certificates built into it?
- Or is the fault with Azure? Should the server that this is running on have the correct set of root certificates set up?
- Or am I supposed to do something?

I tried running similar code on my own machine and had similar problems, even after deleting all the expired certificates from the Windows Certificate store.

Here is the error that is being thrown in the Azure Function app:

```
Result: Failure Exception: AggregateError: RequestError: certificate has expired 
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/got/dist/source/core/index.js:953:111) 
at ClientRequest.origin.emit (C:/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/@szmarczak/http-timer/dist/source/index.js:39:20) RequestError: certificate has expired 
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/got/dist/source/core/index.js:953:111) 
at ClientRequest.origin.emit (C:/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/@szmarczak/http-timer/dist/source/index.js:39:20) Stack: AggregateError: RequestError: certificate has expired at ClientRequest.<anonymous>
```

The actual trigger for this is my first call

```
import { Issuer } from 'openid-client';

// ...

// This line of code throws the exception
const laqorrIssuer = await Issuer.discover(clientMetaData.laqorr_api_base);
```

Comment: Some information in other questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21004645/where-is-nodes-certificate-sto

Comment: You need to update your OS to update your trustStore

Comment: @slebetman - I don't think that would make a difference.  My current undestanding is that node doesn't pay attention to any OS-installed certificate store. It just has a hard-coded list of root certificates.

Comment: If that is your theory then you need to update node.js because none of my node applications are affected (and yes, my servers all use Letsencrypt). I'm running 14.15.1. However I personally believe that on Linux and MacOS node uses the OS truststore. I don't use Windows so I don't know how node works on Windows.

Comment: From my own personal observation (I've seen at least 7 questions on Stackoverflow or Serverfault or Superuser) all the people having this problem does not periodically update their OS.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to get your Node application working urgently, just add this line of code at the start.

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0'
```

This will disable certificate validation altogether. Obviously, this is not an acceptable long-term solution.

---

The thing that ultimately solved the problem was restarting the Windows web servers the Node app was communicating with.
I didn't think I would need to do this because my Chrome browser could query the same servers with no problems. There must be some difference between Node and the Chrome Browser. The act of restarting the servers the clients were talking to was enough to get around this difference.

Here's some more information that I came up with while fumbling around.

**LetsEncrypt**

Lets Encrypt originally used a particular certificate as the Root Certification Authority: **DST Root CA X3**. It's validity range was from 2000-10-01 to 2021-10-01. It's no longer valid.

Lets Encrypt now uses **ISRG Root X1** as the root certification authority. It has a valid date range of 2015-06-04 to 2035-06-04. If a platform doesn't recognize this root certification authority, it will not trust Lets Encrypt.

**Node**

Updating certificate stores in your operating system will have no effect on the NodeJS platform.

Node uses a hardcoded list of certification authorities, defined in [node_root_certs.h](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/e46c680bf2b211bbd52cf959ca17ee98c7f657f5/src/node_root_certs.h). (See [this readme](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/e46c680bf2b211bbd52cf959ca17ee98c7f657f5/doc/guides/maintaining-root-certs.md) for more details).

The up-to-date certificate `ISRG Root X1` has been part of Node since version `8.0.0`.
(See [this commit](https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/6331b63ce0e99bc1e5de4e21ea0c9da9df8ab759)).

---

Finally, if you want to write a tiny node application to test if a web request will work: here is one.

```
const got = require('got');

(async () => {
    try {
        // Change this to the url you want to test
        const url = 'https://letsencrpt.org';

        console.log(`Reading from ${url}`);
        const response = await got(url);
        console.log(response.body);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error}`);
        if(error.response) {
            console.log(error.response.body);
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, have you tried upgrading to node v14.18.0 yet?
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40283#issuecomment-932621074

Comment: @SagarKalburgi - As it turns out, I didn't need to. Once I restarted the Windows web servers the node application was talking to, it worked, even on node v12.21.0.