# Letsencrypt CA cert expired: Nodejs application running on alpine 3.14 unable to invoke HTTPS endpoint via axios after using the new LE CA Cert

Tags: node.js, axios, lets-encrypt

I have a nodejs application running on a container based on alpine 3.14. Due to the recent expiration of the Letsencrypt CA cert on Sept 30, it was unable to invoke an HTTPS endpoint via axios because of the expired CA cert as it was getting the error that the actual cert on the endpoint has expired, although the cert was valid.
I went through solutions posted online to overcome this issue. Particularly the solution mentioned here commenting DST_Root_CA_X3.crt from /etc/ca-certificates.conf this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69408777/4178878

I get the error

> "unable to get issuer certificate"

I also tried the solution highlighted as FIX on this answer that mentions about adding X1 and X2 and Intermediate R3: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69411107/4178878

Yet I get the same error

> "unable to get issuer certificate"

Any inputs appreciated!

Comment: Here's a related question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69445796/letsencrypt-root-certificate-expiry-breaks-azure-function-node-application
Changing the certificates on your server will not help, because Node ignores them. It just uses a hardcoded list of root certificate authorities.

Comment: Are you running Node version 8 or greater? Is the HTTPS endpoint provided by a Windows Server? Have you tried restarting the Windows Server?